# re-enable dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, bootloader

I recently installed windows 10 on a new SSD, the hard drive that I used before was set-up for dual booting (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04).

How do I boot the Ubuntu 16.04 on my old hard drive?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS boot? Are both systems in same boot mode? If same boot mode, it may be just `sudo update-grub`.  If that does not work, post link to summary report from Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

install grub to the MBR on the 2nd drive. For me this is `/dev/sdb`. Grub will list your Linux OS as well as your Windows OS in its menu so you can boot either system.

sloved this problem when use [bootrepair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

[RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)